# EF Core IQueryable ordering by child property

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to build an extension method to IQueryable which can sort a collection by entity child property.

I have the following class:

```
public class ViewPaymentOrder : Entity
{
  public string ClientName { get; set; }
  // ... other properties

  public PaymentOrderME PaymentOrderME { get; set; }
}
```

And I need to sort by `PaymentOrderME.RegisterDate`.

I have this function that works fine to sort by `ViewPaymentOrder` properties:

```
public static IQueryable<T> OrderByField<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, string field, bool isDescending = true)
{
    var type = typeof(T);
    var property = type.GetProperty(field);
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(type, "p");
    var propertyAccess = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(parameter, property);
    var arguments = Expression.Lambda(propertyAccess, parameter);

    var resultExp = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable),
        isDescending ? "OrderByDescending" : "OrderBy",
        new[] { type, property.PropertyType },
        source.Expression, arguments);

    return source.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(resultExp);
}
```

For example, by calling

```
IQueryable<ViewPaymentOrder> query;
//...
query.OrderByField(nameof(ViewPaymentOrder.ClientName), isDescending);
```

It sort perfectly.

How can I adapt this function to be able to sort by `PaymentOrderME` class properties?

Something like this

```
IQueryable<ViewPaymentOrder> query;
//...
query.OrderByField(nameof(ViewPaymentOrder.PaymentOrderME.RegisterDate), isDescending);
```

Comment: I will give a try. Thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately does not work. By calling query.ApplyOrderBy(new[] { Tuple.Create(nameof(ViewPaymentOrder.PaymentOrderME.RegisterDate), isDescending) }) a got this error: 'RegisterDate' is not a member of type 'Bt.CambioOn.Domain.Entities.ViewPaymentOrder'. Am I Doing something wrong?

Comment: Sure you are doing it wrong: ` query.ApplyOrderBy(new[] { Tuple.Create("PaymentOrderME.RegisterDate", isDescending) })`

Comment: Sorry my friend! I'm kind of stupid sometimes. That works like a charm. Thank you very much!